# Rails helper with block and parameter for block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, block, helper

I'm trying to implement something like this in Rails 2.3.10:

```
<% helper_method(collection) do |object| %>
   <p> <%= object %> </p>
<% end %>
```

The result of this helper would be something like:

```
<li> <p> Object 1 </p> </li>
<li> <p> Object 2 </p> </li>
```

Essentially the method would wrap each `<p>` with a `<li>`. 
I'm not sure if my approach is the best and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I read about `capture(&block)` and `concat` but I can't seem to be able to access the `object` parameter.

Thx.

Comment: Are you using Rails 2 or 3? Helpers are very different in 3.

Comment: I am using Rails 2.3.10. I've added that detail in the question. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 2.3.x

```
def helper_method(collection, &block)
  concat(capture(collection, &block))
end
```

Comment: Cheers! In my case I had to iterate through the collection and do content << capture(object, &block). The only problem now is that the actual content is not rendered on the screen. Any ideas ?

Comment: I got it, I should have returned `concat content` instead of just `content`.